# Setting default timezone in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

i have this code to show and hide a certain element at a given time:

```
function live(){
    var now = new Date();
    var elm = document.getElementById("live");
    if(now.getDay() == 0 && (now.getHours() >= 11 && now.getHours() <= 13)) {
        elm.style.display = 'block';
    } else{
        elm.style.display = 'none';
    }      
}
```

However, this wont work as expected because i need the time to be in Japan time, not the users time. How can i set the default timezone?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to initialize javascript date to a particular timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-javascript-date-to-a-particular-timezone)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [timezone-js](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js). Something like this could work:

```
var dt = new timezoneJS.Date("2014/05/04 10:10:30 +0000", 'Europe/London');
dt.setTimezone("Asia/Jakarta"); // You can check if they have Japan specific, if not you can probably create a new timezone with +0900
console.debug(dt); //return formatted date-time in asia/Jakarta
```

Some users have problems with this though and tend to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) instead:

```
moment.tz("2014-04-05 11:55", "Tokyo").format(); // "2013-11-18T11:55:00-05:00"
```

[Available timezones in moment.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/data/)

Comment: Hi, after doing that i would only need to write below my code as normal?

Comment: I'm not sure, try it out.

Comment: timezone-js has been archived. Downwoting bececause of this, the answer has aged ...